# Algorithm to determine whether two periodic sequences of intervals have a nonempty intersection

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, modulo

I am looking for an algorithm that, given natural parameters l1, n1, m1, l2, n2, m2, and size,
answers "true" if and only if there exists natural numbers k1, k2, r1, r2 such that:

l1 + k1*m1 + r1 = l2 + k2*m2 + r2

with the constraints k1 <= n1, k2 <= n2, r1 < size, r2 < size and r1 <> r2.

The obvious solution is linear in min(n1, n2). I am looking for something a little more efficient.

### Context

I am trying to implement in a static analyzer a check for C99 rule 6.5.16.1:3

> If the value being stored in an object is read from another object
>   that overlaps in any way the storage of the first object, then the
>   overlap shall be exact [...] otherwise, the behavior is
>   undefined.

When the analyzer encounters an assignment `*p1 = *p2;` where `p1` and `p2` may point into the same block, it must check that the zones pointed by `p1` and `p2` do not overlap in a way forbidden by the above rule. The parameter "size" above corresponds to the size of the type pointed by `p1` and `p2`. This size is statically known. The offsets that `p1` are known to point to inside the block are represented as a set l1 + k1*m1 with l1 and m1 fixed, known natural integers and k1 varying between 0 and n1 (n1 is also fixed and known). Similarly, the offsets `p2` is known to point to are of the form l2 + k2*m2 for some known l2, m2 and n2. The equation l1 + k1*m1 + r1 = l2 + k2*m2 + r2 corresponds to the existence of some overlapping offsets. The condition r1 <> r2 corresponds to the case where the overlap is not exact, when the analyzer must warn.

Comment: Can you give an example set of parameters?

Comment: @vhallac l1=0, m1 = 512, n1 = 1000, l2=128, m2 = 760, n2 = 300, size = 128.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you are looking for the solution to a linear system of congruences.  The [Chinese remainder theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) should be applicable.  It won't apply your bounds checking, but if it finds a solution you can then check bounds yourself trivially.

EDIT: Forget the CRT.

Assuming `size <= m1` and `size <= m2`, model the low (inclusive) and high (exclusive) edges of your memory regions as linear relations:

```
addr1low = l1 + k1*m1
addr1high = addr1low + size = l1 + k1*m1 + size
addr2low = l2 + k2*m2
addr2high = addr2low + size = l2 + k2*m2 + size
```

You want to know if there exist `k1, k2` in range such that `addr1low < addr2low < addr1high` or `addr1low < addr2high < addr1high`.  Note the exclusive inequalities; this way we avoid *exactly* overlapping ranges.

Suppose `m1 = m2 = m`.  Consider:

```
addr1low < addr2low
l1 + k1*m < l2 + k2*m
(k1 - k2) * m < l2 - l1
k1 - k2 < (l2 - l1) / m

addr2low < addr1high
l2 + k2*m < l1 + k1*m + size
l2 - l1 < (k1 - k2) * m + size
(l2 - l1 - size) < (k1 - k2) * m
(l2 - l1 - size) / m < k1 - k2
```

The progression above is reversible.  Assuming `k1, k2` may be 0, `-n2 <= k1 - k2 <= n1`.  If there is an integer in range between `(l2 - l1 - size) / m` and `(l2 - l1) / m`, then the system holds and there is an overlap.  That is, if `ceil(max((l2 - l1 - size) / m, -n2)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1) / m, n1))`.  The other case (`addr1low < addr2high < addr1high`) proceeds similarly:

```
addr1low < addr2high
l1 + k1*m < l2 + k2*m + size
// ..
(l1 - l2 - size) / m < k2 - k1

addr2high < addr1high
addr2low + size < addr1low + size
addr2low < addr1low
// ..
k2 - k1 < (l1 - l2) / m
```

Now the test becomes `ceil(max((l1 - l2 - size) / m, -n1)) <= floor(min((l1 - l2) / m, n2))`.

Now consider `m1 <> m1`, and without loss of generality take `m1 < m2`.

Treating the variables as continuous, solve the intersections:

```
addr1low < addr2low
l1 + k*m1 < l2 + k*m2
(l1 - l2) < k * (m2 - m1)
(l1 - l2) / (m2 - m1) < k

addr2low < addr1high
l2 + k*m2 < l1 + k*m1 + size
l2 - l1 - size < k * (m1 - m2)
(l2 - l1 - size) / (m1 - m2) > k  // m1 - m2 < 0
```

Again, the steps are reversible, so any integer `k < min(n1, n2)` that satisfies the bounds will make the system hold.  That is, it holds if `ceil(max((l1 - l2) / (m2 - m1), 0)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1 - size) / (m1 - m2), n1, n2))`.  The other case:

```
addr1low < addr2high
l1 + k*m1 < l2 + k*m2 + size
l1 - l2 - size < k * (m2 - m1)
(l1 - l2 - size) / (m2 - m1) < k

addr2high < addr1high
addr2low + size < addr1low + size
addr2low < addr1low
l2 + k*m2 < l1 + k*m1
l2 - l1 < k * (m1 - m2)
(l2 - l1) / (m1 - m2) > k   // m1 - m2 < 0
```

Here the test becomes `ceil(max((l1 - l2 - size) / (m2 - m1), 0)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1) / (m1 - m2), n1, n2))`.

The final pseudo code might look something like this:

```
intersectos?(l1, n1, m1, l2, n2, m2, size) {
  if (m1 == m2) {
    return ceil(max((l2 - l1 - size) / m, -n2)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1) / m, n1)) ||
           ceil(max((l1 - l2 - size) / m, -n1)) <= floor(min((l1 - l2) / m, n2));
  }

  if (m1 > m2) {
    swap the arguments
  }

  return ceil(max((l1 - l2) / (m2 - m1), 0)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1 - size) / (m1 - m2), n1, n2)) ||
         ceil(max((l1 - l2 - size) / (m2 - m1), 0)) <= floor(min((l2 - l1) / (m1 - m2), n1, n2));
}
```

Comment: Yes, I'd check that the bounds make a nonempty intersection possible first, since that's the easy part. Could you perhaps expand your answer into an actual algorithm? The way I see it right now is still linear in size, which can be large (yes, I'm slow).

Comment: The free term `r2-r1` makes it very difficult to convert to a CRT. But maybe O(size) would be better than O(min(n1, n2)). :) But still it hurts that `m1` and `m2` are not coprime - which is required for CRT.

Comment: +1 for nice and detailed derivation. One question, though: I don't get the `k` in the `m1 <> m2` case. If there is no such `k`, isn't it still possible that there may be some `k1`, `k2` where `k1 <> k2` that satisfy the inequalities?

Comment: Yea, you may be right.  If m1 <> m2, then the addr(k) linears intersect, and do at most once (so, the common k exists and is unique.)   However, it may be that the bounds check on the intersection fails and yet the regions overlap elsewhere..

Answer (score 2):

### 1. A small improvement to the obvious algorithm

The mutual arrangement of p1 and p2 is periodic with the period equal to lcm(m1, m2) = m1 * m2 / gcd(m1, m2). In the obvious solution, suppose you iterate over k1 from 0 to n1. Due to the mentioned repetition pattern you can stop as soon as you reach m2 / gcd(m1, m2). I assume you have already reduced (l1, n1) to the intersection only.

### 2. A more tricky approach

Let's reformulate the question: is the minimal non-zero distance between p1 and p2 less than size?

First, let's consider p1-p2. Then we'll add p2-p1 to the mix.

So we want to find the minimal non-zero value for

p1 - p2 = (l1 + k1*m1) - (l2 + k2*m2) = (l1-l2) + (k1*m1 - k2*m2).

Let d = gcd(m1, m2). If we permit k1 and k2 to take arbitrary integer values the set of all possible values of k1*m1 - k2*m2 is exactly the same as the set of all possible values of k*d for arbitrary integer k.

Hence the minimal non-zero value of (l1-l2) + (k1*m1 - k2*m2) is (l1-l2) mod d if it's non-zero or d otherwise. Here, mod gives a positive result even if (l1-l2) is negative.

Let's find minimal such k1 and k2. Extended Euclidean algorithm gives us a1 and a2 (possibly negative) such that d = a1*m1 - a2*m2. The solution is unique up to addition of 0 = (m2/d)*m1 - (m1/d)*m2. Then

(l1-l2) mod d = (l1-l2) + k * d

(l1-l2) mod d = (l1-l2) + k * (a1*m1 - a2*m2)

(l1-l2) mod d = (l1-l2) + (k*a1) * m1 - (k*a2) * m2

Add or subtract 0 = (m2/d)*m1 - (m1/d)*m2 enough times so that coefficients of m1 and of m2 are both positive and minimal at that. This gives you the position where p2 come to p1 at the distance (l1-l2) mod d for the first time.

If just found k1 and k2 are in bounds and (l1-l2) mod d is non-zero then this answers the question positively. Otherwise repeat the same for (l1-l2) mod d + d. And keep repeating until you reach size.

Then repeat for p2-p1 instead of p1-p2.

If none of the steps gave a positive answer then the answer is negative.

The complexity of this algorithm is O(size / gcd(m1, m2)).

Which algorithm to prefer in every specific case depends on particular numbers. Computing gcd is not free too (O(log(min(m1, m2)))).